# How to embed fonts from Apple Font Book

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm constantly finding cool fonts on websites and downloading them to the Apple Font Book on my Mac, but I can't figure out how to embed them into an HTML page. This very well may not be possible, but if anyone knows how to do this, I will be eternally grateful!!!

Comment: Note that this might in fact not be legal in the slightest, so always double-check the license. And also, if you do find cool fonts that you want to use on a web page, first check to see if there's an official font pack, or web distribution that you can use (e.g. does it google webfonts entry? etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can include font assets in your app by copying the font you have in your Font Book and having them in a folder such as /static/fonts. you can then include them as follows:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: <font name here>;
  src: url(<path-to-your-font>) format(<appropriate-font-format>);
}

div {
  font-family: <font name here>;
}
```

Note: Different browsers support different font filetypes. I recommend you check out the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts) for more info on that.

Comment: this is what https://caniuse.com is for, don't rely on MDN for accurate support matrices. Basically _everything_ including IE supports WOFF, and everything except for IE supports WOFF2, so in 2021 the rule is "use WOFF2 with WOFF fallback". On that note: your answer doesn't include the critically important `format(...)` part of the `src` value.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have edited the answer to include the format.